# Add a Textbox to DataGrid

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am using .NET Compact Framework for C# and Visual Studio 2005.

How can we add a `TextBox` to a `DataGrid` using Compact Framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking about adding a TextBox column in you DataGrid, this should work:

```
DataGridTableStyle dgts = new DataGridTableStyle();
dgts.MappingName = "Cars";

DataGridTextBoxColumn nameColumn = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
nameColumn.MappingName = "Name";
nameColumn.HeaderText = "Car name";
nameColumn.Width = 80;
dgts.GridColumnStyles.Add(nameColumn);

dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(dgts);
```